# How to display list of resource drawables

Tags: android

I would like to display all resource drawables in a list so that the user can select one. Is there any way to loop through all R.drawable items so I don't have to hard code them into my program?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the getFields method on the drawable class, you are able to iterate through the entire list of drawables.

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html

Comment: using `android.R` will give only the native drawables in the Android SDK. In order to get your app's drawables, use `com.example.appname.R`

Comment: Why are you catching a generic exception?

Comment: I'm not sure - it has been quite a while since I wrote this answer. There must of been a reason..

Comment: awesome! i needed a list of font resources and `R.font.class.getFields()` worked great.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside your generated R.drawable object you will see that the IDs are contiguous, in my case (and probably yours) beginning at 0x7f020000. As they seem to be sorted by alpha you could probably add dummy images AAAAAAA.png and ZZZZZZ.png and iterate between the two IDs exclusively.

I can't endorse your reasons for attempting this, but I reckon that would work.

Comment: You are right. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131585/1287856
It also works to iterate in the raw/ folder as well as the xml/ folder.