# Android (min 2.1): load images from name string

Tags: android

I want to be able to load images dynamically from res/drawable.  I don't how many files there will be, but I do know they will be named by convention as "image_N", where N is sequential integer.  It is possible that new images will be uploaded while the app is running.

My code is basically

```
Resources rs = getResources();
String imgName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/drawable/image_" + i;
int imgID = rs.getIdentifier(imgName , null, getPackageName());

if (imgID != 0)
{
    Drawable d = rs.getDrawable(imgID);
    //etc.
}
```

but `imgID` being returned is always `0`.

I also tried another approach

```
String imgName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/drawable/image_" + i;
b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgName);
if (b != null)
//etc
```

But `b` is always `null`.

I know there are files in the folder with the right names because I put a few there.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've mistaken compiled resources with files inside folders. In Android, resources are static as far as I know. Once compiled you can't add new resources by dropping files inside "drawable" folder, there would be no IDs for new files.
You should use a folder in DATA or better ask Android API with getFilesDir() or something similar.

For more info, take a look >>[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Ah!  Thank you.  If that's true, it makes things simultaneously easier and more difficult for me.  :)  The default images that I put in my res/drawable I should just be able to refer to directly (perhaps via a foreach statement?) while the others I will need to go through the file resources - or perhaps the load through URL API.

Comment: For the default list of images in R.drawable, I found that part of the solution (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/3950277/1181368].

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using [getIdentifier(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) incorrectly.  This should work:

```
int id = Context.getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + i, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

which would is equivilent for an id `R.drawable.image_<+i>`

Comment: My final code does indeed have a line that looks like that.  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
String drawableName = "drawableNameAsDeclaredInDrawableDir" // in your case "image_" + i;
int drawableResId = resources.getIdentifier(packageName + ":drawable/" + drawableName, null, null);
```

Then use

```
Drawable d = resources.getDrawable(drawableResId);
```

Comment: Btw as ruhalde pointed out you cannot add drawable resources at runtime. You will have to load new images on the sd card or internal memory.

Comment: Hi YuviDroid - thanks!  But your code is basically identical to mine, no?  Except it looks like you leave out `"android:resource//"`.

Answer (score 0):

in Adapter i use this

```
   Context context;
   public MyAdapter0(Context context, 
   List<String>   moduleList,List<String> moduleList2) {
   mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   for (int i=0;i<moduleList.size();i++) {
   int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("color6_"+i,
   "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    mItems.add(new Item(moduleList.get(i),moduleList2.get(i),id));
   // Log.d("idimage", String.valueOf(R.drawable.color6));
    }
```