# Generate image with dynamic string in android

Tags: android, string, image-processing, dynamic

How could I programatically generate an image (ie output_file.png) which is a combination of user input (ie. strings) overlaid on top of another image file?

Hopefully the image below can illustrate it better

[image: Mockup]

Comment: This might help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575746/android-min-2-1-load-images-from-name-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write text directly into a bitmap you can do something similar to the following:

```
        int textSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);  
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        myCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); 
        myCanvas.drawText(string, x, y, paint);
```

To write the bitmap to a file you can read the answer to this question here: [Convert Bitmap to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769806/convert-bitmap-to-file)

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually need to create an image? Are you trying to save it/share it or just display text overlaying an image?

If you just need to overlay, you can set a textview to overlay the image using a RelativeLayout.

If you want to save and share the image, you should take a look at 
[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Comment: If you display this using a TextView overlaying the ImageView, you could have a live preview (even one that updates dynamically as they type.)  Pushing a "save" button would then generate the bitmap using the method for which I provided the link. You could popup a preview of this generated bitmap for final confirmation before saving to file if you wanted.