# How to read many file from raw resource in loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, resources

I have many text files and want to put them in a for loop.

I get an Extra that have Resource name from last activity (s)
and have an array that have Resource name of
my text files in raw Resource is from {d0,d1,d2,d3, ...,d79}
and I want to check name(s) and array name and put the find name to resource!
I have error on (res=R.raw.(d[i]))
my code :

```
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <=79; i = i + 1) {
        if (s.equals(d[i])){
            res=R.raw.(d[i])
        }
    } 
    inputstream = getResources().openRawResource(res);
```

Comment: check Matt's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for fetching resource id dynamically,

```
ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 79; i++) {
  id.add(getResources().getIdentifier("d"+i, "raw", getPackageName()));
}
```

Now you will have all the resources id's inside id ArrayList

Comment: i put this , but i get force close ???                           int id[] = new int[79];                    
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 79; i++) {
                       id[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("d"+i, "raw", getPackageName());
                       if (s.equals(d[i]))     {res=id[i];z=d[i];}
                    }

Answer (score 0):

I have 6 variations of resources in one place I need to read.

```
    try
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
         {
              String fname = "p" + i;
              int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "drawable", "com.example.yourproject");
              if (id == 0)
              {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Lookup id for resource '"+fname+"' failed");
                  // graceful error handling code here
              }
             scoresBm[i] =  (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
         }
    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
    }
```