# play new audio tracks on clicking Next

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am trying to develop a language learning app where I  play dialog lines on a button click (5-10 seconds each). 
So, I created arrays of dialog lines for each dialog, i.e:
**currentAudioArray {"line0", "line2", "line3"}**
They are names of the audio files placed in res/raw folder

But I can't get to play them the way I need.
 I am using **MediaPlayer.create()** method, but it seems that it only takes direct links to specific files (i.e. R.raw.mySoundfile).

How can I feed an array usingsomething like looping [i] into **MediaPlayer.create()**? Or is there **any other class or method** to play a next audio file on a NEXT button click?

So far I tried using:
    mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(Listen.this, currentAudioArray[0]));
    mediaPlayer.start();

But it gives me "unresolved method" error because it does not like currentAudioArray[0] being a string and not URL.

I also tried:
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentAudioArray[0])

but this also gives arrows once it gets to mediaPlayer.prepare().

Any suggestions or ideas on how to play those files in array are very very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you need to keep in mind:

You are using the same instance for all the tracks. So whenever you click 'next', you have to **stop** and **dispose** the `MediaPlayer` which is currently playing.

If you're getting an error, try to re-initialize the `MediaPlayer` instance and `Create()` it again: `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mySoundfile);` instead of the `setDataSource` method

Check this question if you need to loop through the "raw" folder:
[How to read many file from raw resource in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472506/how-to-read-many-file-from-raw-resource-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found my problem!
Originally I set my array of audio files as **strings**:

`String[] currentAudioArray {"line0", "line2", "line3"}`. But instead I should have set them as **int** and also add R.raw path like this:

`int[] currentAudioArray {R.raw.line0, R.rawline2, R.raw.line3}`

In this case:  `mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(Listen.this, currentAudioArray[i]))` did not have any problems with integer values.

So it worked!
Hope it helps someone else!