# Saving multiple images to external storage android

Tags: android

I have more then 50 images in my res/drawable folder. I want to save these images to external storage and then display these image one by one in an image view/image switcher. I used below code to save single image to external storage.  but i am unable to figure it out how can i save all these images to external storage altogether (at once).

```
public void SaveImage(){
    if (!CheckExternalStorage()) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a01);
    try {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "image1.png");
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Image Written to Exterbal Storage");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a `for(...)` loop?

Comment: @Stochastically Yes it is a good idea but how can iterate loop over this line     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a01);

Comment: Looks like the answer has found a way :-).

Comment: :-/ I vll give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an answer from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221787/794088  with some modification to call your method `SaveImage` with a param

```
...
R.drawable drawableResources = new R.drawable();
Class<R.drawable> c = R.drawable.class;
Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

for (int i = 0, max = fields.length; i < max; i++) {
    final int resourceId;
    try {
        resourceId = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);
        // call save with param of resourceId
        SaveImage(resourceId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}

...

public void SaveImage(int resId){
    if (!CheckExternalStorage()) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
    try {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, "image1.png");
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Image Written to Exterbal Storage");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: please, dont forget to upvote the linked answer at the top (if you found it useful).