# count how many pictures in drawable directory android project

Tags: android, image, count, drawable

I need help to count how many pictures in drawable with criteria substring filename? like how many pictures with filename starting "SC" ?

Comment: Great then, go ahead and try.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object

Comment: You want to count particular pictures with starting some name.. Then use `Asset` instead of Drawables.

Comment: Also look at this one http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for that. Simply use `getDeclaredFields()` to get all fields of `R.drawable.class`. Then, just loop through them, look for the search term in the field names and get the drawable using `Resources.getDrawable(Field.getInt());`.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I haven't tried it but you can use getFields() to get all the variables

```
R.drawable.class.getFields()
```

Then you can perform your search for specific file name accordingly.

See this to know more for Reflections in Java: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/