# What is the path directory to res/drawable type String to pass through File(String path) in Android?

Tags: android, path, directory, android-drawable

I am trying to get String path directory to  images in the res/drawable and filter through it (jpg, png ..) 
Something like this

```
    File folder = new File("/res/drawable");
    images = folder.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER);
    File image = images[randGen.nextInt(images.length)];
```

From sd card works easily but couldn't make it from the resource folder! I don't know if this is naive question but I have been trying different options like passing through uri, casting bitmap to File, no luck!

Comment: You can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object

Comment: Thanks I am checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get String path directory to images in the res/drawable

Resources are not files on the device. They are entries in the APK's ZIP file. Hence, you cannot construct a `File` that points to a resource.

You can use `AssetManager` to list assets, open `InputStreams` on assets, etc.