# Android - How to get the names of pictures in drawable folder?

Tags: android

I´m creating a game for my college project and I was wondering if I can get the names(just the names) of the images I put inside the /drawable folder in android. It can also be the files I put inside the /raw folder, the option that works better.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object

Comment: thanks, but do you have an exeample about how to use this AssetManager? how can I obtain an instance of it?

Comment: @FabioPhillipRochaMarques http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()

Answer (score 1):

Use the following snippet

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
     for (Field f : ID_Fields) {
        try {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + "sample");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```