# NullPointerException when showing folder content as listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to show the files on a folder created on /raw and the app crashes. Here is the code (The logcat says the nullpointer is triggered by the line "filesName = new String[fileList.length];)

```
package com.estudiable.estudiable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.File;


public class Categoria_Emprendimiento extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria__emprendimiento);

    File dir = new File("/raw/Emprendimiento");
    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
    String[] filesName;
    filesName = new String[fileList.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < filesName.length; i++) {
        filesName[i] = fileList[i].getName();

        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filesName);

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.categoria__emprendimiento, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}


And the logCat is:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.estudiable.
estudiable/com.estudiable.estudiable.Categoria_Emprendimiento}
: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.estudiable.estudiable.Categoria_Emprendimiento.onCreate(Categoria_Emprendimiento.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT trying the proposed solution** (The files are now in a subfolder in the assets folder. It gaves me an error. How should I use it properly?)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria__emprendimiento);

    File dir = new File("assets/Emprendimiento");
    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
    String[] filesName = getAssets().list("assets/Emprendimiento");
    for (int i = 0; i < filesName.length; i++) {
        filesName[i] = fileList[i].getName();
    }

        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filesName);
```

**EDIT 2** From getAssets() to the semicolon is underlined in red. What am I missing?

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria__emprendimiento);

    String[] filesName = getAssets().list("app/src/main/assets/Emprendimiento");


    /* File dir = new File("/raw/Emprendimiento");
    //File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
    //String[] filesName = new String[fileList.length];
    //for (int i = 0; i < filesName.length; i++) {
    //filesName[i] = fileList[i].getName();

    //new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filesName);*/

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the application `raw` folder, or a folder in the phone internal memory that his called `raw` ?

Comment: About the application raw folder. I want to list files (text in .html) to open them later in a webView.

Comment: <img src="http://imgur.com/9OuvYYO">

Comment: You can't have subfolders in an app resource folder. Is you project compiling ?

Comment: Yeah. It launches and everything works except that.

Comment: Should I put the files in another place then?

Comment: the filesName array already contains the files name, remove your for loop completely.

Comment: It doesn´t work. The second part of the statement is in red and it says "unhandled exception:java.io.IOException"

Comment: Also remove your `dir` and `fileList` completely.

Comment: I updated the code leaving it like in the last edit. It still not works. I'm surely missing something. Thank you anyways, Stephane :)

Comment: You still need to create the ArrayAdapter, get the list view (with `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id)` and call setAdapter on the listview. But that is not related to the original question. I would recommend you to read tutorials about listview and adapter.

Comment: I'm already on it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: If the part to get the files name worked, then you should mark my answer as accepted and maybe upvote it.

Comment: Nothing worked but I'll mark it as accepted due to yout effort. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the files are in the app, and can't be changed without publishing, I would recommend just manually creating a list of string that contains the name of all the files.

Then with the name you can get the id with :

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

That will be the same integer as `R.raw.xxxx`, which will be used to read the file.

There is a way -dirty- to iterate through resources, but you'll get the integer value and not the name ([in case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221787/1318795)).

---

Or, if you put your files in the assets folder, you can list them like that :

```
String[] fileNames =getAssets().list("myFolder");
```

Comment: Dang, I was planning to put (in several folders) around 100 files. I'm new at programming, Is this thing that difficult? :'(

Comment: There should be no need to retrieve a list of all resources since you have to put them inside you app and can access them with the R class. If you have a lots of files, maybe you should name them `something_0001`, `something_0002`, so you can just iterate through the names easily.

Comment: Hmmm. The thing I'm trying to do is create several folders (one per category) and then show a listview of each category with the files on that folder to open them from there. If I put them all in a unique folder, how could I categorize them? . Is not possible to do it the other way by tweaking the code? Thanks a lot for your time. I really apreciate it :)

Comment: You can have subfolders in the asset folder because it is apart from the res folder.

Comment: Ok, I put what you said there but it's wrong. How should I tweak the block? Sorry, I'm really new with this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `/raw/Emprendimiento` directory contains any files?

If you get a NPE on `filesName = new String[fileList.length];`, it means that `fileList` is `null`, which means that the `listFiles()` method returns `null`.