# How to write an array which stores the images from the drawable folder?

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, android-studio, baseadapter

Can i know what did i do wrong? i just wanna get my images from drawable folder and pass it to my adapter to display on my gridView.. But i dont know how to add inside the array.. The error message is at the line

```
arrImages[i] = this.getResources().getIdentifier(wd.getName(), "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Anybody wants to help me :( I wanna load it dynamically according to the names in my database.. the database name (wd.getName()) is the same as my file name.png

Declare at the top :

```
    int arrImages [] = {};
```

Inside onCreate :

```
    int i = 0;
    for (Words wd : words)
    {

        String log = "Id: " + wd.getId() + " ,Name: " + wd.getName();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("wordList : ", log);

        arrImages[i] = this.getResources().getIdentifier(wd.getName(), "drawable", this.getPackageName());

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: You want to load dynamically r statically ?  Statically means @Hanish Sharma answer vll do it.

Comment: @KingofMasses dynamically of course..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object

Comment: i dont wanna load ALL of my drawable folder's images.. i just wanna load those who have the wd.getName() pictures only.. @KingofMasses

Comment: @KingofMasses is my array implemented it wrongly? cause i saw some of them declare like : images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it using dynamic way.

Implementing new array list :

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I can store all my images dynamically inside.

This is the looping from my database, adding the resource id from drawable folder to my array :

```
for (Words wd : words)
    {
        String log = "Id: " + wd.getId() + " ,Name: " + wd.getName() ;
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("wordList : ", log);

        arrImages.add( this.getResources().getIdentifier(wd.getName(), "drawable", this.getPackageName()));

    }
```

Comment: Good. It will help some one in future !!

Answer (score 3):

// references to our images

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

Here is the array of your images in drawable folder.
Now use this array in the array adapter of grid view.
This is the easy method. 
For more understanding please visit this link

> http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/02/display-images-in-gridview.html#.VekddOSqrCY

Comment: actually i wanna take it dynamically and my name of the pictures are not in order...