# How to set Image from drawable folder into the layout instead of String url

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have one Activity Class where Image are displayed in Grid view of 2 column. I use the following code to display the images

```html
public class BooksPage extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    String image[] = {  "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51cGqWqQPJL._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
            ,"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91WAYiiPwML.jpg"
            ,"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51CEndEnxCL._SX383_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
            ,"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-textnook/bookimages/9788185749815.jpg"
            ,"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51DyYdNU5mL.jpg"
            ,"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61yhyD3HvkL.jpg"
            ,"http://www.skkatariaandsons.com/Best%20Sellers/978-81-85749-73-0.jpg"
            ,"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81FGjPtdvnL.jpg"};
    String stream[]= {"MSC Physics","MSC Chemistry","MSC Biology",
            "MSC Geology","BBS|BBA","CA","Bachelor","+2 Science"};
    TextView navName,navEmail;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_books_page);
       


        

        RecyclerView favPlaces = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.favPlaces);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        favPlaces.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        favPlaces.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<BookDetails> placeList = getPlaces();

        StaggeredAdapter staggeredAdapter = new StaggeredAdapter(this,placeList);
        favPlaces.setAdapter(staggeredAdapter);
        navName.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("name","null"));
        navEmail.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("email","null"));
    }
    private ArrayList<BookDetails> getPlaces() {
        ArrayList<BookDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index=0; index<image.length;index++){
            details.add(new BookDetails(image[index],stream[index]));
        }
        return details;
    }


    }
}
```

But instead of using url, I would like to use the image from the drawable folder.

How can I do that..Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an array which stores the images from the drawable folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389904/how-to-write-an-array-which-stores-the-images-from-the-drawable-folder)

Answer (score 3):

You need create an array of integers with the images in the drawable folder.

**Code:**

```
        //Array of images from drawable folder
        int images[] = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,...};

        //Your method still working without problem.
        private ArrayList<BookDetails> getPlaces() {
            ArrayList<BookDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < images.length; index++){
                details.add(new BookDetails(image[index],stream[index]));
            }
            return details;
        }
```

You maybe need adapt your **BookDetails** class because now you are using an integer instead of String and you should change **StaggeredAdapter** to load the image from resource and not from url.

I hope it helps you.