# Adding a drawable to resources programmatically and getting the list of all drawables programmatically

Tags: android

I need to implement the following functionality: download an image from the internet, and add it as a drawable to resources.

I will also need to get a list of all drawables programmatically when app starts. I can get a drawable from resources by it's id, but the list of drawables will be dynamic, so I will not have the IDs of the drawables.

If someone has a solution for this, help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> download an image from the internet, and add it as a drawable to resources.

That is not possible. Resources are read-only at runtime. You are welcome to download the image to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and use it from there.

> I will also need to get a list of all drawables programmatically when app starts

For the ones you download to internal storage, use standard Java file I/O to list the files in your chosen directory (e.g., [`listFiles()` on the `File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) pointing to that directory).

For any actual drawable resources that you want to look up dynamically, that's not really recommended. That being said, you can [hack in some reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221787/115145) to make it work.