# How can I use project folders(drawable, raws, etc) as directories inside the application?

Tags: java, android, drawable, fileinputstream

If I want to access a directory, I would to the following:

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir()+"/name");
```

And then, if `f` is a directory, I can iterate through the files and do a lot of things.

Can I do the same with the drawable/raw folder? I know how to get the id of a file using the name or the name using the id, but I am not sure how can I use drawable as a directory. I also need to use FileInputStream on some files, so I need a file type, not an id or a name.

I found some 'some what' related questions, like this one: [Retrieving all Drawable resources from Resources object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221603/android-retrieving-all-drawable-resources-from-resources-object)

But my problem is a bit different. I know how to get a resource in this way. By getting the id you can do lots of things, but as far as I know, you can not use FileInputStream. That's what I need: the possibility to use FileInputStream on a resource that is inside a project folder(drawable or raw).

Comment: Copy the files in the internal storage! And start using them its easy especially when they are in assets folder

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do the same with the drawable/raw folder?

Not really.

> the possibility to use FileInputStream on a resource that is inside a project folder(drawable or raw)

Resources are not files. You cannot get a `FileInputStream` on them.

For raw resources, you can call `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object to get an `InputStream`, though.