# android raw resource

Tags: android

is there any way to get the file names stored in the res/raw folder programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need that? Usually that's not a good idea and indicates that you have to work on your apps design. Probably you'd better store your images at `/assets` folder or have an additional xml listing all of them. Anyhow [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538380/how-to-display-list-of-resource-drawables/2539031#2539031) how you can do that foe `res/drawables` folder. So implementing that for `res/raw` is as simple as:

```
Field[] raw = R.raw.class.getFields();
for (Field r : raw) {
    try {
        System.out.println("R.raw." + r.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```