# How to access different 'global' elements without array? (Java)

Tags: java, android

I'm currently doing Android development.

The class R (an automatically-generated class) has lots of 'global' values accessed from anywhere like so:

```
R.drawable.<file_name_ignoring_suffix>
```

I have lots of files named 'item_0.png', 'item_1.png', 'item_2.png' etc.

Is there an easy way to iterate through these items without putting them into an array first?

My current implementation:

```
int[] itemResources = { R.drawable.item_0, R.drawable.item_1, R.drawable.item_2,
                        R.drawable.item_3, R.drawable.item_4, R.drawable.item_5  };
```

... then iterating through the array.

This works well, but it isn't particularly maintainable, and gets laborious when I have many items.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*global elements*"? To me it's not a specific terminology.

Comment: @Lion I used quote symbols around the word 'global' since I use the term loosely. I'm aware that there are no such things as global variables in Java, but I'm referring to variables declared by `public final static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to get the list of fields of `R.drawable`.  It's kind of hacky, but it might work for you.

Comment: Here is the relevant SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538380/how-to-display-list-of-resource-drawables  This does what Keith is referring to as "use reflection".

Comment: Very intriguing answer. I'm reading the article as we speak. @hopia This answer is interesting, also. To make it work for my situation, I could manipulate the strings provided by f.getName() to identify which 'set' of images the image in question belongs to (since I have 'items', 'coins', 'powerups' etc.) Thanks, both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no easy way to do it. Here is small code i tried to get the drawables.

```
    R.drawable d = new R.drawable();
    try {
        for (Field fld : declaredFields) {
            Integer id = fld.getInt(d);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
            if (bitmap != null)
                Log.d("tag", "success");
            else
                Log.d("tag", "failed");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("tag", "" + e);
    }
```

In the above test, some of them failed. I dont know the reason as it need further investigation. But this will get you started.

Secondly, also look for [this api from theme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes%28android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29), if you want to pick the right png using the rules that android platform uses for find the suitable resource based on the orientation, locale etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting them in a same directory, then automatically querying the directory content and have it create an array using the contents?