# How to get list of images from res folder in android

Tags: android

In my project I want to add a lot of new images and delete others and I want to get list of all my drawables in res folder in activity. How do I can get it? Or should I use assests folder and get list of images from there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538380/how-to-display-list-of-resource-drawables  has the answer to this.

Comment: Ok, how can I cast these fields to Drawable? I'm very newbie in programming.

Comment: There is already a post that describes an strategy to get the images that you need in this folder, based in a prefix and in the method getResources().getIdentifier(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
Field[] list = R.drawable.class.getFields();
BitmapDrawable[] drawables=new BitmapDrawable[list.length];
for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
int id=list[i].getInt(null);
try{
drawables[i]=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(id);
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Hope this helps!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ok, and then? How to cast this to Drawable ?

Comment: Tell me what you actually needs to do. Do you want to do something like converting that to a bitmap.

Comment: Yes, I want to get list of images like BitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void searchSDCardForImage() {

        String path = null;

        String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        String condition = uri + " like '%/GetImageFromThisDirectory/%'";
        String[] projection = { uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE };
        Vector additionalFiles = null;
        try {
            if (additionalFiles == null) {
                additionalFiles = new Vector<String>();
            }



            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    condition, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                boolean isDataPresent = cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (isDataPresent) {

                    do {

                        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(uri));
System.out.println("...path..."+path);
additionalFiles.add(path);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: this is not what he wants

Comment: That's not really what I want but maybe i use it lately.

Comment: @tyczj, i'm sorry. bad english knowledge... do you want me to delete my answer ?