# how to get the list of images that are in drawale folder

Tags: android, drawable, assets

I have a folder witch contains sub folders. There are Images in Sub Folders and the Number of Images varies from folder to folder. How i can get the List of all images from Drawable by java. following is the code for the assets folder. I want like this for Drawable

```
   String[] files = assetManager.list("Deaf/0"+possition);
```

Comment: your images available into Drawable. am i right?

Comment: yes images are in Drawable folder

Comment: take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538380/how-to-display-list-of-resource-drawables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to Create `int[] Array` that store all your images id like:

```
int[] type_img=new int[]{R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5};
```

And load your images into loop like:

```
for(int i=0;i<type_img.length();i++){
        image_view.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(type_img[i])));
    }
```

Comment: I want to get names of all images in a list,my Main folder has sub folders and each sub folder has different numbers of images.