# Android How can I load every images from the drawable folder using file to set into the imageItems?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, drawable, bitmapfactory

How can I load image from drawable folder when I don't know image file name.

I want to show all the drawable folder image in the gridview.

I just know how to load the Image from file name, like below:

```
 // ImageItem  method :public ImageItem(Bitmap imageBitmap, String title){...}
   private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData()
     {
         final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
         TypedArray imgs = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);

         for( int i = 0 ; i< imgs.length(); i++ )
         {
             Bitmap bitmap =      BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
             imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
         }

         return imageItems;
     }
```

But now  if I don't know file name(R.drawable.filename), How can I load every images from the drawable folder using file to set into the imageItems?

Thank you very much.

Comment: One google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538380/how-to-display-list-of-resource-drawables

Answer (score 0):

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        Log.i("LOG", "R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

try this